# Filter redux state based on specific url to display one product and it's variations

Tags: javascript, reactjs, drupal, redux, react-redux

I'm currently setting up a drupal based e-commerce react site. I already have it set up to make api calls and store data in my react app. When I console log I'm getting my current 3 products, and I'm getting another array of all the product variations. It's all there in the state.

Also, I have a page that displays product details. It shows description, color options, size options, etc. Right now I have it set up where when I click the link from the product selector in my app, it moves to the product page with a url containing the name of the product I clicked and displays the correct product description. However, I need to filter it so that the redux state only includes that product and it's relevant variations. Hopefully that makes sense...

Not sure what you guys need to see from the app in order to understand my issue so please let me know and I will add them to clarify. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have not provided any part of your code, I have assumed some of it.

I hope this helps:

```
class ProductPage extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { productDetails: {}, relatedProducts: [] };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    // considering your product URL looks like domain.com/product/product-name
    const productName = window.location.pathname.split('/')[2];
    const productDetails = this.props.productList.find(product => product.name === productName);
    const relatedProducts = this.props.productList.filter(product => // determine how a product can be considered as related to the current product);
    this.setState({ productDetails, relatedProducts });
  }

  render() {
    // render codes...
  }
}

export default connect(
  state => ({
    productList: state.products // or whatever the name of your reducer for your product list in redux store
  })
)(ProductPage);
```